# How to override password protection for a single referring domain

Tags: .htaccess

Tried lots of "solutions" and none of them work.

If i have example.com password protected, but I want anybody (genuinely) visiting from referer.com to have access to it without a password, how do I accomplish that?

Heres my htaccess

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile "/home/username/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Comment: I don't know if that's possible at all, because it doesn't make any sense security-wise.

Comment: I'd avoid against doing this as there is no guarantee that the disclosed "referer.com" address is genuine - it's really easy to spoof this.

Comment: i need an "allow from" statement in there somewhere. That would be secure enough for me.